# Improving Rails user query on huge table (timing out on Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have an issue with one of my pages not loading on Heroku because my query on my Users table is timing out. There is a significant amount of records.

I use the result of the query to render my users as options in a select dropdown tag.

I am currently using ActiveRecord to fetch my records.

`User.where(filters).order(first_name: :asc, last_name: :asc).select(:first_name, :last_name, :id).map{ |u| [u.full_name, u.id] }`

Filters is just a hash that consists of attributes as keys and their respective value. The value can also be an array (i.e. `{ status: ['active', 'inactive'] }`).

I have tried using `find_each` to load batches of users, but it is still not good enough.

```
users = []
User.where(filters).order(first_name: :asc, last_name: :asc).select(:first_name, :last_name, :id).find_each do |group|
 users += group.map{ |u| [u.full_name, u.id] }
end
```

I don't think `full_name` is an issue since it is just a string concatenation method:

```
def full_name
  return nil if first_name.blank? || last_name.blank?
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

**How do I reduce my query time?**

Edit:
Adding an index improved my query performance a lot, but is still timing out on Heroku.

Comment: The full name method does not contain an N+1? Have you tried writing the query so that postgres does everything, including combining the first and last name?

Comment: Can you post the result of: User.where(filters).order(first_name: :asc, last_name: :asc).select(:first_name, :last_name, :id).to_sql

Comment: @John  Here is an example with a filter:  `"SELECT first_name, last_name, id FROM \"users\"  WHERE \"users\".\"status\" = 'active'  ORDER BY \"users\".\"first_name\" ASC, \"users\".\"last_name\" ASC"`

Comment: @penner I haven't. I don't much experience in the realm of writing raw queries. Do you think this is the limitation of using an ORM and I should look into writing a query?

Comment: How many filters do you usually use? Have you tried indexing first_name and last_name since you're sorting on them?

Comment: I typically have 3 filters (region, current_stage, status). Good idea on adding the index - I'll try removing the sorting for now to see if that's the issue.

Comment: @John The index helped improved the query a lot (it occasionally loads now), but it is still slow and timing out. I'll keep trying to improve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.where(filters).order(first_name: :asc, last_name: :asc).select("last_name||', '||first_name as full_name, first_name, last_name, id")
```

Loading all the records into memory just to concatenate strings is a big performance hit. Also having a select of 500+ users is a bad idea. You should look into an api endpoint and an ajax typeahead search.

Concatenating the strings in the select with an alias (using `as`) will allow you to access the alias as if it were a column, e.g.:

```
@users.map{|u| u.full_name}
```